# C# Pasar dataTable a web service SOAP

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Tengo una duda en cuanto a envío de información a un Web Service. Desde código tengo un DataTable que se llena con una consulta a Base de Datos, el cual quiero enviar al Web Service en formato xml.

¿Cómo enviar un DataTable a un webservice en formato XML?

Código de DataTable:

```
public void consultaUSistema(DataGridView datagridView)
{
    string sXMLparam = "";
    DataSet dtsCatalogo = new DataSet();

    sXMLparam = "<root><accion>C</accion>";
    sXMLparam += "</root>";

    ReaderAndWriter.ConnectionString = Constants.connectionString1;
    try
    {
        dtsCatalogo = ReaderAndWriter.OneParameterStoreProcCaller("SP", sXMLparam);
        datagridView.DataSource = dtsCatalogo.Tables[0];

        if (dtsCatalogo.Tables[0] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dtsCatalogo.Tables[0]; //aquí se llena el dataTable


        }
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Si agregas parte de tu código donde esta tu dataTable seria mas sencillo ayudarte.

Comment: Cuál es el problema en concreto que se te presenta ?

Comment: Necesito enviar el DataTable como parámetro al Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes convertir directamente tu DataSet a xml

```
string XML= dtsCatalogo.GetXml();
```